# How to create iText BaseFont based on InputStream

Tags: java, fonts, itext, inputstream

I have a font file "arial.ttf" in a web application and I can only obtain its contents as `InputStream`.

```
InputStream inputFont = getResourceAsStream("/resources/arial.ttf");
```

How can I create an [iText `BaseFont`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/BaseFont.html) based on the `InputStream`? The `createFont` method doesn't accept it.

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(inputFont, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

> createFont(InputStream,String,boolean) can't invoke createFont(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,boolean) 
>    in BaseFont.

Comment: What is BaseFont? It's not in the normal JDK.

Comment: @aryn.galadar it is in itext. 99maas: can't you include that information?

Comment: and `BaseFont` has no `createFont` method which accepts an InputStream.

Comment: If the font isn't available on the file system, you'll need to read the font file into a byte array and use the BaseFont.createFont(String, String, boolean, boolean, byte[], byte[]) constructor. See the iText javadoc for more info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like the following:

```
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
        .getResourceAsStream("/resources/arial.ttf"));
BaseFont.createFont("arial.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_Harial.ttf, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, true, bytes, null);
```

You have to specify the **.ttf** in the font name to tell the method it should interpret it as ttf format.

Answer (score 0):

**InputStream** is not allowed as parameter in **createFont** method.

We can convert inputStream to byte array data to create the font, or can get file and do directly like code below:

```
byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(Path.of("/resources/arial.ttf")); 
final BaseFont bfbold = BaseFont.createFont("arial.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, true, data, null);
```

If you are accessing to **external Url**, the **byte array data** should get:

```
byte [] data = null;
try(InputStream in = new URL("https://p7qp.blob.core.windows.net/font/arial.ttf?sv=2021-08-06&ss=bf&srt=co&se=2022-08-token").openStream()){
                data = in.readAllBytes();
} //using try(){} here to auto close the inputstream after finished task
```

Explain a little bit about parameter in **createFont** method.

```
public static BaseFont createFont(String name, String encoding, boolean embedded,
                                  boolean cached,
                                  byte[] ttfAfm,
                                  byte[] pfb)throws DocumentException,
                                  IOException { ... }
```

**Parameters:**

- name - the name of the font or its location on file
- encoding - the encoding to be applied to this font
- embedded - true if the font is to    be embedded in the PDF
- cached - true if the font comes from the cache    or is added to the
  cache if new, false if the font is always created    new
- ttfAfm - the true type font or the afm in a byte array
- pfb - the    pfb in a byte array

References: [link](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.itextpdf/itextpdf/5.4.1/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/BaseFont.html#createFont(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20byte%5B%5D,%20byte%5B%5D))